# WSO2 IS SAML Response Missing Attribute Statement

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, qliksense

I had tried WSO2 Identity Server integrated with QlikSense  by SAML 2 Protocol .

The Statckoverflow doesn't allow embed image，Sorry.

I had setted WSO2 SP Configuration and Qliksense Server SAML2 Configuration ，but logs of Qliksense display "Exists SAML Attribute statement : 0".

The SAML authenticate process has Failed in SAML Response to Qliksense。

Also, I just found WSO2 SAML Response missing the tag of "attribute statement " 。

**SAML Response(SP:QlikSense):** 
[miss attribure statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA4Sj.png)

[WSO2 Log Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdlcE.png)

I think the key point is "Invalid AttributeConsumingServiceIndex in AuthnRequest "

Is it any possible edit AttributeConsumingServiceindex in WSO2 Configuration?

Comment: The QlikSense SAML Protocol :[Figure](https://community.qlik.com/servlet/JiveServlet/showImage/38-4569-107851/pastedImage_2.png)

Comment: Did you select "Enable Attribute Profile" in SP https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0

Comment: yes,i am select "Enable Attribute Profile"，but WSO2 Response without Attribute Statement

Comment: Also, try to set some requested claims in "Claim Configuration" of the service provider. And make sure they have non empty values in the user profile. (eg: email, nationality etc.)

Comment: I have setting "Claim Configuration" to eamillAddress or Givename，and use "admin" to login . and then,IN the log has display the Claim message and admin [Figure] (https://i.imgur.com/BsZ5uqt.png) ,thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not sending the correct AttributeConsumingServiceIndex value in your SAML request which is correspond to the WSO2 SP.
You can find the AttributeConsumingServiceIndex from the Issuer list view of your SP.

- Click on your SP
- Expand Inbound Authentication Configuration -> SAML2 Web SSO Configuration
- Here the Issuer list view shows the "Attribute Consuming Service Index" value.
- Either you have to include this value in the SAML authentication request's AttributeConsumingServiceIndex attribute or you have to omit this attribute in the SAML request.

Comment: Hi,i just try to find how to setting the WSO2 Attribute consuming Service Index,but no result.(Figure:[WSO2](https://i.imgur.com/agmWa2s.png))  The qliksense saml request attribute index is 1(figure:[sense_request](https://i.imgur.com/ls23T0Q.png)),but has no any config file to setting...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Attribute Consuming Service Index from WSO2 IS and get Qlik working.

Click Browse under Registry in Main tab in IS Management Console.
Navigate to _system >config >repository >identity >SAMLSSO
Under this directory, you will find one file for each SAML SSO service provider you have configured in IS. File name does not have any resemblance to the SP, so you will have to check each to find what it is.
Once you click on the file it will go to the Detail view, (Originally it is in Tree View by default)
In detailed view, you can check Properties for that SP by clicking the "+" icon on the right side of Properties tab. (With the properties identify the correct file for Qlik )
You will see AttributeConsumingServiceIndex property in the list.
Change this value to 1 and save property.
Restart the server and try Qlik login again

Comment: no problem. I recently published [this](https://medium.com/@nuwandiwickramasinghe/saml-attributeconsumingserviceindex-in-wso2-identity-server-5d7aef37050b#.yo4oghuel) post on the subject. Sharing in case.